# Installing PyTorch on Jetson Nano Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pytorch

I am trying to install PyTorch on Jetson Nano Ruining Ubuntu 1804. My reference is https://dev.to/evanilukhin/guide-to-install-pytorch-with-cuda-on-ubuntu-18-04-5217

When I try the following command this is what I get:

```
(my_env) crigano@crigano-desktop:~$ python3.8 -m pip install numpy ninja pyyaml mkl mkl-include setuptools cmake cffi typing
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.20.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (12.7 MB)
Collecting ninja
  Using cached ninja-1.10.0.post2.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (818 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mkl
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mkl
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use PyTorch on the bare-metal Jetson Nano, simply install it with [NVIDIA's pre-compiled binary wheel](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1049071/jetson-nano/pytorch-for-jetson-nano/). Other packages can be found in the [Jetson Zoo](https://elinux.org/Jetson_Zoo#PyTorch_.28Caffe2.29).

MKL is developed by Intel "to optimize code for current and future generations **of Intel® CPUs and GPUs**." [[PyPI]](https://pypi.org/project/mkl/). Apparently it does run on other x86-based chips like AMD's (although Intel has historically intentionally crippled the library for non-Intel chips [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library#Performance_and_vendor_lock-in)), but unsurprisingly Intel is not interested in supporting ARM devices and has not ported MKL to ARM architectures.

If your goal is to use MKL for math optimization in `numpy`, `openblas` is a working alternative for ARM. `libopenblas-base:arm64` and `libopenblas-dev:arm64` come pre-installed on NVIDIA's ["L4T PyTorch" Docker images](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:l4t-pytorch). You can confirm that `numpy` detects them with `numpy.__config__.show()`. This is what I get using numpy 1.12 in python 3.69 on the `l4t-pytorch:r32.5.0-pth1.6-py3` image:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

So presumably it will use `openblas` in place of MKL for math optimization. If your use case is also for `numpy` optimization, you can likewise use `openblas` and shouldn't need MKL... which is fortunate, since it isn't available anyway.